# Handling KeyError when accessing multilevel dictionary

Tags: python

In my Python class that is used to process JSON data  I have a number of similarly looking functions, which are doing very simple thing - get nested key value or return default one. Something like this:

```
def get_lat(self):
   detectedLat = ''
   try:
      detectedLat = self.receivedJson['props']['myProps']['details']['location']['coordinates']['lat']
   except KeyError:
      pass
   return detectedLat
```

There is no guarantee that any level given key exists and it is equally likely to be missing `'myProps'` as well as `'lat'`. I am aware that I could use `get()` for this (e.g. because of performance), but in case of nested dictionary, I don't think it'll help, due to at least 2 reasons (maybe more):

1. Default value can be set only for last element to not trigger error
2. Following line: `detectedLat = self.receivedJson['props']['myProps']['details']['location']['coordinates']['lat']` will be even longer, because now we are adding extra 6 `.get()`

I have been also thinking of some kind of helper function e.g.:

```
def get_lat(self):
   detectLat = self._help_parse(['props', 'myProps', 'details', 'location', 'coordinates', 'lat'])
   return ('' if detectLat is None else detectLat)
   
# Taking advantage of fact that receivedJson is class variable)
def _help_parse(self, dict):
   val = None
   for dk in dict:
      val = self.receivedJson.get(dk)
      if val == None:
         return val
   return val
```

But to be honest, I am not sure, whether there isn't any better way to write `_helpe_parse()` without the loop.

Could someone recommend better way (if there is one)?

Comment: Why is it not sufficient to simply catch the KeyError and return the default value, and maybe implement this in your own custom `get_lat(self, defaultval)` method? The KeyError will be thrown if any of the keys are absent.

Comment: @jarmod because when you have 20+ such functions it just looks odd and takes a lot of space for nothing.

Comment: @sebap123 why you don't simply put a try/except block, like in your first code example and return `None` or `''` inside the `except KeyError:` part. Also, what do you mean by *"looks odd and takes a lot of space"*?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński imagine having functions like `get_lat`, `get_lng`, `get_height`, `get_temp`, `get_water`, `get_xyz` and so on (this is rather big JSON I'm working with). Now take the function I posted in question `get_lat` and copy it for each of mentioned functions only changing key values at some levels. This way you have 6+ `try/except` blocks. Add to this fact that `try/except` can be slower (timeit showed around 4x slower).

Comment: Alright, makes sense. Though this question is better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this'll work for your exact use-case, but this will recursively access a dictionary given an arbitrary number of `(key, default_value)` pairs:

```py
from typing import Tuple, Any, Hashable


def recursive_get(d: dict, default: Any, *keys: Tuple[Hashable]) -> Any:
    if not keys or not isinstance(d, dict):
        return d
    return recursive_get(d.get(keys[0], default), default, *keys[1:])
```

Usage:

```py
In [5]: d
Out[5]: {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': {'e': {'f': 'value_f'}}}}}}

In [6]: recursive_get(d, "default value!", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
Out[6]: 'value_f'

In [7]: recursive_get(d, "default value!", "a", "b", "c", 0, "e", "f")
Out[7]: 'default value!'

In [8]: recursive_get(d, "default value!", "a", "b", "c", "d")
Out[8]: {'e': {'f': 'value_f'}}
```

Comment: I think this is too complex approach, because I don't need default for any level. I need only value of last level (most inner) key-value pair, or default if ANY key is missing.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. See my edit.